# Can Sharepoint be setup to crop or resize uploaded image automatically?

Tags: image-display, image-upload

When an image is uploaded for an article in SharePoint, can SharePoint be setup to resize the image or crop the image based on pre-set dimension?

For Example:

If a user uploaded a 640 x 480 image, can the image be cropped and resized to be:
320 x 200?

Comment: good idea . this is strange that we cant googling and find any open source solution on github or codeplex but i think we should do crops with human experience with Microsoft picture manager because code (computer or algorithms) don't know which crops place can be better for you?

Answer (score 1):

If its SharePoint 2013, then you can use Image Renditions. This allows you to convert images to different dimensions and keep the actual file intact.

I don't think there is any automatic ways to apply this behavior.

One approach is to attach and `ItemAdded` event receiver and then modify the uploaded file using Image Manipulation APIs'.

For cropping images you can use http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing